# Is this constructor violating the Single Responsibility Principle?

Tags: c#, constructor, coding-style, solid-principles

I'm trying to force myself to use SOLID principles and write unit testable code. Lately, I have been getting paranoid and indecisive when writing code because I get the feeling that I'm always violating some principle.

Consider the class below. JavascriptPropertyInitializer is responsible for detecting a list of properties that have a special attribute in a given class, and rendering some javaScript code. Does it have too many responsibilities? Is the constructor doing too much?

I know I'm instantiating a dictionary in the constructor and I'm aware that instantiating concrete objects is a known violation. Yeah, I know, I'm supposed to inject it via the constructor, but why? What's the harm of my class depending on a concrete dictionary?

```
public class JavascriptPropertyInitializer
{
    private readonly HtmlTextWriter _writer;
    private readonly object _containerObject;
    private readonly string _javascriptObjectName;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _settings;
    private List<PropertyInfo> _customWebControls;

    public JavascriptPropertyInitializer(HtmlTextWriter writer, object containerObject, string javascriptObjectName)
    {
        _writer = writer;
        _containerObject = containerObject;
        _javascriptObjectName = javascriptObjectName;
        _settings = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        ValidateParameters(writer, containerObject, javascriptObjectName);
        DetectCustomWebControls();
        CollectSettings();
    }

    public void Render() 
    {
        RenderJSProperties();
    }
}
```

Comment: The last 2 method calls from constructor seem too much for me

Comment: @Alex, Yeah, for me too, but if I put them in Render(), then Render() would violate SRP. Where would you put them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be migrated to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary here is almost a primitive type; Its used to store key value pairs, and nothing else(?). I can't see you ever needing to swap it out for a different implementation, which is where IOC would be useful.
The writer makes more sense being IOC'd (which you did): I can see a need to output as xml later, or as a string, etc.

On the "too many responsibilites" side. From your sentence describing what this class does, 1) detects special attributes, 2) renders some js. There could be potential for splitting here. What if this class just detected the properties and returned those detected properties in a C# object. Then some other class, JavascriptRenderer maybe, could take in those properties and translate to javascript.

```
var pi = JavascriptPropertyInitializer(containerObject, javscriptObjectName);
var r = JavascriptRenderer(writer);
var output = r.Render(pi.DetectAttributes());
```

I often times also find myself getting paranoid about not following coding principles. At this time, I just try my best. I apply principles when it is obvious or useful, but when I am uncertain I try not to worry about it too much and move on. I comfort myself in knowing I can go back and refactor when my code becomes painful to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

The Single-Responsibility Principle is defined as follows:

> A class should have only one reason to change.

So this is all about finding a right wording for the reason. However, the reason only makes sense in the context, in other words, on a particular level of abstraction. By moving through levels of abstraction the code changes its conformance to the Single-Responsibility Principle.

Your experience is probably related to the fact that your knowledge of the framework you use improves so your understanding is moving to the more concrete abstractions (close to the framework internals). At this level your code is doing too much (as you foresee many reasons to change). Do a mental exercise and try to move to abstractions of your application, what it does and why and re-evaluate the conformance to the SRP.